# Odoo. How to translate menu items?

Tags: python, odoo

I working with odoo and I need to translate all menu items.

[image]

Can you provide an example step by step how I can do this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroLobito yes. I had tried. But I got the error 
`ValueError: Wrong value for res.users.lang: u'en_US'`. Something like [THIS](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4453). After error I set English language to active in db, because I can't run app for translations. The error disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate Menus you need to follow these steps.

**1. Settings => Translation => Load Translation.**

[image]

**2. Select Proper Language and Click Load button.**

**3. Open User Preferences.**

[image]

**4. Now change the language from user preferences and menus language will be changed.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and a special thank you for screens. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much! Good luck in development! ;)

Answer (score 0):

2 projects to become familiar with are gettext() (in the standard lib https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gettext.html#module-gettext) and the Babel project. http://babel.pocoo.org.

There are a few ways to translate these strings:
The process is like this for most websites.  You will need to modify the templates to use substitution strings for the internationalization process so your link for "Reporting" becomes {links['reporting']}.  After that you will need to have localized mappings of strings from reference_language->some_other_language.

Check out this video from pycon for a nicer introduction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAHMmy7dqUU

FYI: There are services to do the translation for you if you are unsure of the translation.